# How to update authority on a rugged project?

Tags: spl-token, cli, authority

The project I'm working on has been hijacked and rugged by the ex-developer who had the authority account.
Long story-short, he minted new tokens, then he emptied the liquidity pool.

We still have the owner account so I tried to change the authority wallet, but it failed with this error:

> RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error
> processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4 [5 log messages]

This is the CLI line I used for trying to change the mint authority:

```
spl-token authorize Token_Address mint New_Authority_Address
```

I looked up the 0x4 error and it looks like it means *"/// Owner does not match."*
But this is not true.
Running "spl-token account-info token_address" shows our wallet as the Owner.

I also tried running "spl-token revoke token_account_address" but it returns:

```
No delegate on account
```

Does anyone know how I can update the authority account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`No delegate on account` means that there is no delegate to revoke on the token account.

`spl-token authorize Token_Address mint New_Authority_Address` would fail with  `Owner does not match` because whatever mint you're trying to update is not owned by the address provided.

I would recommend transferring to a new token account and working from there. Assume anything else compromised.

Comment: The ex-developer&thief was the one who minted the old token.
We created a new token eventually. I was hoping that we could somehow regain control of the old one to at least change its symbol and name. 
Thank you very much for your answer!